# Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrape

I want to crawl restaurant data from https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty
each restaurant page is reached by the url such as https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/la-pizza-2
Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from satu.items import QuoteItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuotesSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wolt'
    allowed_domains = ['wolt.com']
    start_urls = ['https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/']

    handle_httpstatus_list = [404, 302]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('/restaurant/')), callback='parse_item'))

    def parse_item(self, response):

        try:
            title = response.xpath(
                ".//div[@class='VenueHeroBanner__container___1_lK2']/h1[@class='VenueHeroBanner__title___2EzpN']//text()").get()
        except:
            title = ['']

        try:
            time = response.xpath(
                ".//div[@class='VenueSide__infoLine___jrSHX']/div[@class='VenueSide__hours___122Zm']//text()").get()
        except:
            time = ['']

        item = QuoteItem()
        item["title"] = title
        item["time"] = time

        yield item
```

However, it does not scrape any data. And I don't know where is the issue.
Output is like this:

```
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.1 started (bot: satu)
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 20.3.0, Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 2
3 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.1.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020), cryptography 2.9.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.selectreactor.SelectReactor
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'satu',
 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 32,
 'COOKIES_ENABLED': False,
 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 3,
 'HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES': [301, 302],
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'satu.spiders',
 'REDIRECT_ENABLED': False,
 'RETRY_HTTP_CODES': [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408, 429],
 'RETRY_TIMES': 1,
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['satu.spiders'],
 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 '
               '(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2919.83 Safari/537.36'}
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-05-22 00:13:40 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-05-22 00:13:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/> (failed 1 times): 404 Not Found
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/> (failed 2 times): 404 Not Found
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/> (failed 2 times): 404 Not Found
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/> (referer: None)
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 622,
 ...
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 21, 18, 13, 40, 862817)}
2020-05-22 00:13:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your spider starts at https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/ which is a 404 page (aka not found). You should change your `start_urls` to something with data like https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/la-pizza-2. Also, you did not define a parse method which is the default hook if you do not override [start_requests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests). Then there is an error in your xpath for time, you're missing a `/div`.
Try this

```py
class QuotesSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wolt'
    allowed_domains = ['wolt.com']
    start_urls = ['https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/la-pizza-2']

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath(".//div[@class='VenueHeroBanner__container___1_lK2']/h1[@class='VenueHeroBanner__title___2EzpN']/text()").get()
        time = response.xpath(".//div[@class='VenueSide__infoLine___jrSHX']/div[@class='VenueSide__hours___122Zm']/div/text()").get()
        yield QuoteItem(title=title, time=time)
```

Comment: thank you for your contribution. Yet, changing the `start_urls` to something like https://wolt.com/ru/kaz/almaty/restaurant/la-pizza-2 didn't solve the issue. I still receive the same output with no data scraped

Comment: @SultanAkhmetbek Yeah, I found some more issues as well on closer inspection. Edited my answer, please try it!